# how innodb resolve in-flight transaction？

Tags: mysql

client submits a commit statement and receives a message stating that communication failed. This type of failure can occur for several reasons, including a database instance failure or network outage. In this scenario, the client does not know the state of the transaction.

how innodb resolve such in-flight transaction？
the transaction is success or fail ？

Comment: Ignoring your specific question on innodb and thinking theoretically, the failure may occur at any single step of the request processing and hence it would not be recommended to rely on what the DB is capable to do when there is a failure. Imagine that you send a request and the communication fails when the DB wishes to tell you "Yes, I did it" (moreover, imagine that you have a **mediator** in-between and the failure is in the communication between the mediator and the client).

Answer (score 1):

From InnoDB's perspective, a transaction is either running or not.  If not, it has either been committed or rolled back.

From the client's perspective, this is indeed an ambiguous situation.

It is impossible for the client to recover the session, since a network error sufficiently severe to cause the condition is also by definition sufficiently severe that the session (that is, the database connection owning the transaction) is not recoverable.

If the server received the commit and responded with an OK packet, but a network error prevented the client from receiving the OK, then the transaction was committed before the error occurred.  A network error delivering the OK packet to the client would be expected to force the connection closed, but the transaction has been committed, so it would of course remain so.

On the other hand, if the network error prevented the client's `COMMIT` message from reaching the server, then two states are possible:

- the network error also resulted in the TCP connection to the server being closed from the server's perspective -- in which case, the transaction rolls back immediately; or
- the network error did not result in the TCP connection to the server being closed, such as might be the case if a stateful network device lost its state tables.  In such a case, the connection would be unusable and unrecoverable.  No further traffic for that connection -- either genuine or spoofed by the network infrastructure -- would likely be received by the server, so the transaction remains uncommitted, running, holding whatever locks may have been held, because the server is, initially, unaware that the client has in fact gone away.  The transaction will rollback when the server times out the client connection, or when the IP stack on the server's host forces an error on the connection because TCP keepalives failed.

Both of these scenarios roll back the transaction, one immediately, one eventually.

If, prior to the error, the client had been aware of its connection identifier (`SELECT CONNECTION_ID()`), and if connectivity then was restored, it could reconnect to the server and query the `PROCESSLIST` and `INNODB_TRX` tables inside `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` to discover whether its former connection were still present and whether that connection has a running transaction.

- If its old connection is still present, and has a transaction running, the transaction was not committed.  The old thread should be killed, using `KILL [connection_id]`, so that the transaction rolls back immediately.
- If the old connection is still present, and does not have a transaction running, then the commit succeeded, because there is no other reason for the transaction to be missing if the connection is still there, because the server is unaware of the network error (else the connection would be gone).
- If the old connection is not still present, the status of the former transaction is unknown, except that we know it cannot still be running; it may have been committed or it may have rolled back.  Having retained other information gathered during the previous transaction, such as auto increment values it had been assigned, the client could heuristically determine whether the transaction committed or not.

But this sort of aggressive follow-up to a rare occurrence seems rather excessive for many environments, where a response like "we're sorry, something went wrong while placing your order" might suffice (for a web site) or `500 Internal Server Error` might suffice for an API.

In the case of an API, idempotent tokens are sometimes used to allow the caller to safely retry an operation that failed ambiguously.

Consider, for example, the Amazon EC2 "Run Instances" API. (This is in no way directly related to the question, but it is a well-documented example of the behavior I intend to illustrate, and should make sense in principle, even if you do not use or are unfamiliar with Amazon EC2). This API allows you to start virtual machines, which of of course will cost you money.  What if you got a network timeout when trying to launch a machine?  What about a `500 Internal Server Error` response?  Should you ask again?  Will you now have two virtual machines and pay twice as much as you expected?  No, you won't, because that API [supports an idempotent token](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/Run_Instance_Idempotency.html).  This token makes it safe for you to try again -- if you use the same token to make a semantically-equivalent request -- without the risk of being misunderstood as having wanted to launch two machines.  When they try to process your request, they check whether they've already processed a request with the same token.  If they have, and if it was a request for the same thing, they return the same success response they intended to return the first time, on the assumption you must not have seen the response, for whatever reason.  Similarly, two identical requests with two different tokens are unambigiously interpreted to mean you really do want to launch two machines.

You could accomplish something similar in a MySQL database with a unique key constraint and a unique identifier, like a UUID, which you insert as the transaction is doing its work (or being retried).

If there's already a row in a table you modified with that unique ID when you reconnect and retry, you know the transaction actually was committed (assuming you are using an isolation level of `READ COMMITTED` or higher).

If the row is not there, you know the transaction rolled back -- or that will roll back, in the case where the server is not yet aware that the connection is abandoned.  If the other transaction is still running, the row would appear not to be there (depending, perhaps, on your isolation level -- with `READ UNCOMMITTED`, you might see it) but your transaction should block when it tries to repeat the insert, because the original (still running but destined to fail) transaction holds a conflicting exclusive lock on the row in the unique index.  Trying to insert a duplicate row into a unique key will block until the conflicting lock is released, at which point the insert will succeed if there is no constraint violation.

This is indeed a messy edge case, requiring handling that is appropriate to the importance of the process
 affected.  There is no clean, elegant, simple, straightforward way out if such an error occurs, but hopefully the above is useful information.